# Rails: This SQL query was called multiple times and my be opthimised for eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, query-performance, eager-loading, select-n-plus-1

[image]

I am seeing the above issue in rails simple activerecord query

```
where(email:email).first_or_create!
find_or_create_by!(phone_number: phone_number)
```

Both these queries are not part of any other query meaning not included in any join/includes query. But for an independent query why this issue is coming?

Just because an operation is called multiple times with various inputs can not be called as N+1 query issue.

```
def email_address(email)
  email = email.downcase
  begin
    where(email:email).first_or_create!
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    find_by_email(email)
  end
end

Assume that the method was called [arry_of_emails].map {|x| email_address(x)}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from the controller, just this one action.

Comment: Added the ruby code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning was correct! If you have 27 items in your array it will call DB 27 times!

How we can solve it? I have the next suggestion:

```ruby
    addresses = Address.where(email: params[:emails]) #load all addresses in one request
    list = addresses.inject({}) { |memo, adr|  memo[adr.email] = adr; memo }
    params[:emails].each do |email|
      # if an address is not in our list create new
      Address.create(email: email) unless list.keys?(email)
    end
```

Comment: But the eager loading issue should not be there. Instead it should have told only about number of times SQL queries were made. Even we make 100 calls, it should be legitimate because we have 100 different inputs and we design methods for reusability. Is there any condition like in a request a single SQL type of query should not be  called multiple times? I do not understand clearly How come this is an issue because the warning message is `This SQL query was called multiple times and my be opthimised for eager loading`
In my opinion for eager loading there should be at least 2 tables.

Comment: `Eager loading` is not the only method in ActiveRecord, but it is also a technic for preventing excess amount requests to DB. Your tool doesn't say for using `eager_load` or `include` method. If you want to understand why it complains you need to go deeper to this tool.

Comment: Anyhow I consider the point that `I have to opthimize number of calls to DB` Will vote your answer once my tool did not raise the issue again after the fix you suggested.